# preventDefault on function call

Tags: javascript, axios

This is a 2 part question. The first part is how do you use .preventDefault() in the way I am calling a function?

HTML:

```
<input type="hidden" name="_csrf" value="<%= csrfToken %>">
<a href="#" onclick="deleteItem(this)" class="button gray delete" data-id="<%= products._id %>"><i class="sl sl-icon-close"></i> Delete</a>
```

javascript:

```
const deleteItem = btn => {
  const productId = btn.dataset.id;
  const csrf = btn.parentNode.querySelector("[name=_csrf").value;
  const pendingLi = btn.closest("li");
  FreezeUI({ selector: ".dashboard-list-box", text: "Deleting" });

  axios
    .delete("/account/delete/" + productId, {
      headers: {
        "csrf-token": csrf
      }
    })
    .then(response => {
      UnFreezeUI();
      showSuccess(response);
      fadeOut(pendingLi, "remove");
    })
    .catch(error => {
      showError(error);
    });
};
```

Since I don't have an event in here like:

```
document.body.addEventListener("click", e => {
```

how do I use e.preventDefault() ?

**PART 2 QUESTION:**

Which would be a better way to do this? Like I have with the actually button having `onclick()` or to add an event listener in my scripts.js file or footer? ie: `document.body.addEventListener("click", e => {`

Comment: Inline event listeners are (just like inline styles) generally a very bad idea.

Comment: why don't you want to register your event using `addEventListener`? Being as that solves your problem? You seem to of answered your own question(s)

Comment: I was having a problem with my csrf tokens which I was I tried to change over and that fixed my issue. I prefer to use `addEventListner` actually

Comment: Don't use an anchor, use a  `button type="button"` instead. Picking an inappropriate element for the job causes your problem in the first place.

Comment: Haha, sorry Liam, axios is sending data to node backend. Will remove it from the topic list

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**1st Part Answer**. you can pass event in you method call like

```
<input type="hidden" name="_csrf" value="<%= csrfToken %>">
<a href="#" onclick="deleteItem(event, this)" class="button gray delete" data-id="<%= products._id %>"><i class="sl sl-icon-close"></i> Delete</a>
```

And in you deleteItem method:

```
const deleteItem = (e, btn) => {
  e.preventDefault(); // added prevent default
  const productId = btn.dataset.id;
  const csrf = btn.parentNode.querySelector("[name=_csrf").value;
  const pendingLi = btn.closest("li");
  FreezeUI({ selector: ".dashboard-list-box", text: "Deleting" });

  axios
    .delete("/account/delete/" + productId, {
      headers: {
        "csrf-token": csrf
      }
    })
    .then(response => {
      UnFreezeUI();
      showSuccess(response);
      fadeOut(pendingLi, "remove");
    })
    .catch(error => {
      showError(error);
    });
};
```

**2nd Part Answer:** it is always good practice to use `addEventListner`. this makes your code more manageable/maintainable.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the default event in inline function call like

```
<button type='button' class='close' aria-label='Close' onClick='myfunction(event)'>
```

and in script

```
function myfunction(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    //$(event.target).closest("td").closest("tr").remove();
    // try alert here.. should work
}
```

event and corresponding target can be propagated!

Answer (score 0):

You just pass argument name event. this will pass the event and you can handle it.
I made a small example for you. hope it helps..

```
<html>
<head>
    <script>
        function test(e, btn) {
            console.log(e);//This is the event
            console.log(btn);//This is the button element
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<button onclick="test(event, this)">Test Button</button>
</body>
</html>
```

And for the second question. both ways are good. you should use the way that easier for you to maintenance.